# Adding to my listview using a list of the same type?

Tags: eclipse, list, listview, javafx

I am having problems with adding to a listview strings to it from a list of strings.
here is my code:

```
Stage arg0 = null;
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Browse for Audio File(s)");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.*"), 
            new ExtensionFilter("wav","*.wav"),
            new ExtensionFilter("mp3","*.mp3"),
            new ExtensionFilter( "aac","*.aac")
            );
private ListView<String> playlist;
ObservableList<String> listviewadder;
List<File> selectedFiles ;

selectedFiles = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(arg0);
    for(int j=0;j<selectedFiles.size();j++)
    {
        listviewadder.add(selectedFiles.get(j).getName());
    }
```

but it return error saying " Source not found".
All I want to do is having a list of songs names from the selectedfiles in the file browser.

Comment: Please add details on the error, where does it occur? Any Stracktrace for us? Is it possible that you forgot to set a value to `arg0` prior to showing the `FileChooser`?

Comment: the Problem is in that line : listviewadder.add(selectedFiles.get(j).getName());                                           its not important the error . All what i  need is how to add the names of the files in on the listview from fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(arg0);                                                  i have already checked all the code and i printed out the file names and every thing to the counsel before i tried this.

Comment: If you have a problem and seek help, you can not know what is important and what not for others trying to help you... Your code is running fine on my machine if you initialize the `ObservableList` correctly with for example `ObservableList<String> listviewadder = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`.

Comment: I just figured that out. you were right , I was missing only the initialization of the                                                                                      ObservableList<String> listviewadder = FXCollections.observableArrayList();